# Object is not visible against the background of another object

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, visibility

I have two basic object in the scene
[image]

When I choose orthogonal view (X) the smaller cube is not visible against the background of the bigger one.
[image]

The problem appears in 2.83 and higher. Why can it be?

How it looked in 2.82a:
[image]

Comment: You can show use different colors for a final render. Different colors for the viewport are available. Show all edges is a setting. A light source that is not centered to cast shadows.  Are you concerned about a final render or only the 3D Viewport?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger only in Viewport. Yes, I can use some tricks to avoid the problem, but in 2.82a it looked OK with default settings (I added an image for reference). "Show all edges" didn't help, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is due to outlines settings or around that:

[image]

Comment: no, "Outline' is checked. I tried different colors, tried to uncheck the box and check again - it didn't help.

Comment: This is either in your file or your computer (graphic card?). Could you upload a blend file with the issue?

Comment: Here it is https://dropmefiles.com/pf5Td . I use integrated video for the moment but it is in the list of supported graphics and as I said before - no problem in 2.82.

Comment: Bad news it seems: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m3Hv.png . Worked directly opening your file. So Graphic card... maybe

Comment: If you agree I'll leave the answer as it is as that could have been the issue. But please **don't** accept it.

Comment: OK. Thank you for checking my file.

Answer (score 0):

[[image: wireframe mode]]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lucnx.png)

use wireframe mode :)
good when you need to align an object to a floor in orthogonal mode (the black line, since a plane otherwise might not be seen in a sideview (orthographic))

-sorry for not clarifying the first time...  PS: wireframe is the blue globe in the top in the picture

Comment: It's always helpful to give new users a more accurate description on how to turn on/off options in the Blender UI by using screenshots. Take a look at lemon's answer.